# Electron get httponly cookies

Tags: cookies, http-headers, session-cookies, electron

Is there a way to somehow get the values of httpOnly cookies in electron?

The site I'm pre-loading before my main app loads, sends an httpOnly cookie that has a key inside.
I need this key for my http request headers.

I tried with `webContents.session.cookies` without luck.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to to get an `httpOnly` cookie using Nightmare.js, which uses Electron. Therefore, I think you should be able to achieve that by looking at the source.

Comment: yeah, cypress test runner allows you to get httponly cookies too, even from non-localhost sites if they don't have a good captcha or something. Good reminder to always use 2-factor for logins... https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/getcookie.html#Yields